# Using React-Moment, (moment.js) How do I get date format: Mon Apr 19 1976 09:59:00 from format 2017-08-07 08:42:08?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to convert the date format **`2017-08-07 08:42:08`** to format **`Mon Apr 19 1976 0:59:00`** using `react-moment` library.

I went through the docs at `[https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment][1]` and tried similar examples, but nothing fits my need exactly.

I can do:

```
<Moment fromNow>{datetime}</Moment>
```

yields format:

> in 10 days

But

```
<Moment unix>{datetime}</Moment>
```

yields

> Invalid date

```
<Moment parse="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss">
    {datetime}
</Moment>
```

yields: `Mon Aug 07 2017 08:47:47 GMT+0545`. I don't it without the timezone value at the end. What's the correct parameter for this date format from this input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Moment can parse most standard date formats. Use the parse attribute to tell moment how to parse the given date when non-standard.

https://github.com/headzoo/react-moment#parsing-dates

You can set the output in whatever format you want. [Check out the table of possible tokens](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). Choose the tokens you need and set them on the *format* attribute. Here's some examples:

```
<Moment
  format="YYYY-M-D H:m:s"
  parse="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
>2017-08-18 11:01:21</Moment>
```

With localization:

```
<Moment
  format="LL LT"
  parse="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
>2017-08-18 11:01:21</Moment>
```

With time from now:

```
<Moment
  fromNow
  parse="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
>2017-08-18 11:01:21</Moment>
```

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/q75991v73q).

Comment: This yields Mon Aug 07 2017 08:29:46 GMT+0545. How could I omit the timezone values from it?

Comment: I forgot to add `fromNow` property. I've edited the answer.

Comment: If you prefer to use a _static_ format instead, you can set the `format` property like: `format="YYYY-MM-DD"`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Adding `fromNow` yields a time-ago format. That's not what I want! I did try the static method: `<Moment parse="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss">{datetime}</Moment>` (https://codesandbox.io/s/q75991v73q)  but that gives me correct format with the timezone value. I just want the value without the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation in npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment#formatting) default format that you want. Because that default format of js, as mentioned in [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp)

```
<Moment format="Here desire format">{datetime}</Moment>
```

*optional: Please try to install moment-timezone as mentioned in the link.

Comment: may be Because of T is missing 2017-08-07 08:42:08 , should be 2017-08-07T08:42:08, try by placing hardcoded values.

Comment: Thanks. but what is the correct format for my desired date-time format?

Comment: unix get timestamp value as input.  replace it with {new Date(datetime).getTime()} or any other to get the timestamp format as input

Comment: if moment is not complusory used than you can use simply 

new Date("2017-08-07 08:42:08")
new Date(datetime)

Comment: Sorry, but I tried the things you suggested, none of which work. Can you write an example? Thanks.

Comment: I wrote another answer above with snippets code and output, have u seen those?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have done it using momentjs library

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6KvL.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnWIC.png)

Comment: Thanks. The output includes the timezone format. How do I remove it?